# When to use NSScanner vs. componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: to tokenize NSString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, tokenize, nsscanner

I need to tokenize many strings on an iPhone. Obviously, resources are at a minimum. I have been using `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:` to tokenize my strings, but it is slow. Would it be better to use `NSScanner`? What, generally, are the guidelines one should follow when choosing to use one or the other to tokenize?

Comment: The only way to tell if NSScanner is faster than componentsSeparatedByString is to try it both ways and measure the performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO `NSScanner` is way more flexible than `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet`, so if you need more flexibility - use NSScanner. Regarding performance - you'd have to test for that. So if NSScanner is faster - it has flexibility AND performance advantage (although disadvantage on ease of use).